# React Native 100+ issues in xcode for a new project

Tags: react-native

Why when I init a new react native project:

```
react-native init awesomeProject
```

and run it from XCode I get more the 100+ warnings:

[image: warnings XCode]

Answer (score 0):

Pretty normal, there might be some incompatibilities due to old React Native core code such as deprecated swift methods or maybe old Objective-C code remaining in the core, but are not a problem for you to develop normally. If you don't use third party libraries you might want to try expo!

Expo is an SDK prepared to work along with react native api. It offers you a full javascript built component to use with your React Native code and you can forget about managing the iOS and Android projects as they will do it for you.

If you want to give it a try:
http://www.expo.io